# Customize header and footer with inserted pdf

Tags: pdfpages

I'm trying to customize header and footer while inserting a pdf using a hand-made command: `\setlayout` (3 parameters)

```
\includepdf[pagecommand={\setlayout{Left corner}{Center}{Right corner}}]{my file.pdf}
```

First I tried :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

    \newcommand{\setlayout}{3}
    \thispagestyle{
    \lhead{#1}
    \chead{#2}
    \rhead{#3}
    }

\begin{document} 
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\setlayout{Left corner}{Center}{Right corner}}]{my file.pdf}
\end{document}
```

But, of course, it did not work.

So I would like to create a flexible (as I am going to use it several times) `\setlayout` command in order to customize header and footer only where the pdf is displayed

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippets compilable ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using package `fancyhdr` to define an own style for pages included by `\includepdf`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\setlength\headheight{13.6pt}% as suggested by fancyhdr
\usepackage{mwe}% only for dummy text and example pdf page
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{normal pages}

\fancypagestyle{pdfpages}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[L]{\pdfpagesheaderleft}
  \fancyhead[C]{\pdfpagesheadercenter}
  \fancyhead[R]{\pdfpagesheaderright}
}
\newcommand*\pdfpagesheaderleft{}
\newcommand*\pdfpagesheadercenter{}
\newcommand*\pdfpagesheaderright{}

\newcommand{\setlayout}[3]{\thispagestyle{pdfpages}%
  \gdef\pdfpagesheaderleft{#1}%
  \gdef\pdfpagesheadercenter{#2}%
  \gdef\pdfpagesheaderright{#3}%
}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\includepdf[pages=-,
  pagecommand=\setlayout{Left corner}{Center}{Right corner},
  width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio
]{example-image-a4.pdf}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]